# calculate time between first and last var separated by subgroup in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset which has from-To and an Id. In one Id, there are multiple from-To as sequence and I want to calculate the time difference from the first observation till the last observation for each Id.

In R it looks like:

```
tmp2 <- tmp %>% group_by(Id) %>% slice(c(1,n())) %>% ungroup()
```

Please any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use Min and max functions to get the first and last observations then subtract them to get difference